# How many 3 dB couplers are needed to construct a 16 way fiber optic splitter?

Tags: layer1, cable, fiber, cabling, optics

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_optic_splitter) says we need **31** couplers. Can't we do it with 8 couplers?

Comment: Based on the math in the wiki, (2^4)-1=15.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the math in the wiki article: (2^4)-1=15.

Comment: Bottom-up - 8 to provide 16 end-points. 4 to provide connections to the 8, 2 to provide connections to the 4, 1 to provide connections to the 2. Not shockingly, still 15....